# How to show required form field for association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm new to rails, and I'm not sure how to set up a combobox so that it can be shown as "required" in the browser.  I have a `Product` and a `Location`, and location should be required in a product:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  validates :location, presence: true
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

In my new product form, I have a helper that shows that the field is required, but I'm not sure how best to do that with this associated location. When I try to map it to the `:location` attribute like this:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= show_label f, :location %>
  <%= f.collection_select :location, @locations, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# helper
def show_label(f, attr)
  required = f.object.class.validators_on(attr)
                 .any? { |v| v.kind_of?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator) }
  label = attr.to_s + required ? '*' : ''
  label
end
```

...the `show_label` helper correctly sees that `:location` is required, but the model itself fails to validate after the form is posted because location here is a string (the :id of the location) rather than an actual `Location`.

When I instead use `:location_id`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :location_id, @locations, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

then `show_label` doesn't see that `:location_id` is a required attribute so I don't get the required field annotation, *but* the location gets correctly saved when the model is saved.

What's the right way to render a combobox so I can both recognize if it's a required field AND allow my controller to save my Product?  I feel like I'm probably missing something that competent Rails people all just know.

Comment: What does your `ProductController` look like? Typically you'll need an `if @product.save` block to catch errors. Then you can update the view. with error messages.

Comment: Yes, I am catching any errors in the @product.save and can report them after the fact. My question is mostly about the distinction between `thing` and `thing_id` in associations and in presence validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `validates :location_id, presence: true`. It's not the same as the other validation (you could set an id that does not exist, it will be valid because it's present but it will be an invalid location), so leave the `:location` validation too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a [bunch](https://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012252/rails-4-difference-between-validates-presence-on-id-or-association) [posts](https://forum.upcase.com/t/validate-presence-of-user-id-or-user/6168) on the differences between validating the association and validating the `_id` column, but the rough idea should be to validate both the `_id` column *and* the association.